# Python SMTP.starttls parameters

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm new to python. I've done some study on duck typing of python and I'm stuck in a situation like the following.

When I look in the Python standard library, I find the APIs specify only name of parameters which seem to give a hint on what to be passed but type. This makes me rely on intuition. So it sounds like I'm playing a trial-n-error game when i pass wrong object into function.

For example, in python standard library smtplib, i want to use this function:

`SMTP.starttls([keyfile[, certfile]])`

But i don't know what type of object i should pass into keyfile or certfile parameter? How do I solve this?

Comment: You might want to give an example.

Comment: I find that the documentation does tell the type, and also the semantics, of function and method arguments.

Comment: I edited your question and moved it away from a more argumentative one about duck typing in Python vs. Java. If you phrase your question more specifically it will get a better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably just lack of familiarity with Python and the documentation rather than a duck typing issue.

In your particular example, you have to follow the documentation a bit.

In the `SMTP.starttls()` method, [it says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls):

> If keyfile and certfile are provided, these are passed to the socket
>   module’s [ssl() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#module-ssl).

If you follow that link, you will see:

> The keyfile and certfile parameters specify optional files which
>   contain a certificate to be used to identify the local side of the
>   connection. See the discussion of [Certificates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-certificates) for more information on
>   how the certificate is stored in the certfile.

**Edit:** The `keyfile` and `certfile` parameters appear to be filenames (strings). If you then follow the link to [Certificates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-certificates) you'll see that the files should be in PEM format.

Thanks to J.F. Sebastian for the tip.

Comment: thanks brian, if i want to implement a key object, which method does starttls require from keyfile. will i have to read codes of starttls to see what it needs?

Comment: @user84605: `keyfile` and `certfile` are filenames (`str` objects). The files are in [pem format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html?highlight=ssl#ssl-certificates).